# give JButton multiple options for mouse clicks (Blackjack Game)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, blackjack

I am writing a Blackjack program using JFrame and trying to keep it as simple as possible. My JButton, jbHit works with a single click, however it overwrites the playersHand and playerSide slot with every click. I would like it to work with multiple clicks (3 clicks - since that is the max number of cards you can get after the first two are dealt) options It should count them so to speak so that the array index can record the card image. Here is my ActionListener code that I have so far. I am afraid I am stuck. Should I use some sort of for loop with an int i++?

```
//Hit Button ActionListener
  jbHit.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if ( playerValue < 21 ) {
              //Draw a card
              Card c = deck.drawCard();
              playersHand.add(c);
              playerSide[2].setIcon( new ImageIcon( c.getFilename() ) );
           }
           //If playerValue > 21, bust
           else if ( playerValue > 21 ) {
              //Toggle Buttons
              jbDeal.setEnabled(true);
              jbHit.setEnabled(false);
              jbStand.setEnabled(false);
              jbDoubleDown.setEnabled(false);
              message = "You bust.";
           }
        }
  });
```

Comment: What you probably really need is some kind of model (or two) that can maintain all the information about the current state, the number of cards and their amounts, the round.  You buttons would interact with these models and based on there feedback, via listeners, change there states...

Comment: @MadProgrammer is you want to get that fancy, all you need is to implement a State-Machine, where each context knows the next operation. You can implement this using the State pattern.  I recently designed a Wizard using State pattern to accomplish this. However, the OP wanted to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: @hfontanez Is just another type of model ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I agree, but the OP doesn't want to get that fancy. Which is why I showed a poor excuse for a state-machine by creating an array of Strings to serve as action commands, and then I change them with each button click. It should be simple enough for OP to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array of "action commands" and every time you click the button, the action command changes to the next. If you reach the end, set the index back to zero.  Perhaps something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Action");
    String[] commands = {"command1", "command2", "command3"};

    button.setActionCommand(commands[0]);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource();

            String cmd = btn.getActionCommand();
            System.out.println("Command: " + cmd);

            if(cmd.equals("command1"))
            {
                btn.setActionCommand(commands[1]);
                System.out.println("Command 1 was pressed");
            }
            else if(cmd.equals("command2"))
            {
                btn.setActionCommand(commands[2]);
                System.out.println("Command 2 was pressed");
            }
            else if(cmd.equals("command3"))
            {
                btn.setActionCommand(commands[0]);
                System.out.println("Command 3 was pressed");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
        }
    });
    panel.add(button);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

If you are using Java 7 or later, you can replace the if/else with a Switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a logical flag based on an integer, for example:

```
if(cardsDealt < 3) { 
    // DoThings();
} else {
    return;
}
```

Which would require you to do

```
cardsDealt++;
```

at the bottom of your button click handle.

If this is not what you're asking, please re-explain the question.

Comment: Okay guys I'm getting back into it after electronics class today I'll try all these to see which works best. Thanks everyone for time and help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be a little confused about how jbHit will be called. Realize that it will be called one complete time every time the mouse is clicked. It's not like it inherently knows that it is on the second or third click. Add a class member like int clickCount; that you increment at the appropriate point inside of jbHit. Then you can alter your method's response depending on the value of clickCount.

Comment: I showed a "poor-man's" implementation of a state-machine, by creating an array of Strings (action commands) and where with each button click, the action command changes to the next. So, it can be done.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it can't be done, just to help OP with a misperception that I believe might have been getting in the way. Also, I like your state machine!